# Cross val predict expects as input an already fitted model?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am reading Geron's Hands-on Machine Learning. In page 90, there is a section about Confusion Matrix. He says that we need some predictions, so he does the following:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_predict

y_train_pred = cross_val_predict(sgd_clf, X_train, y_train5, cv=3)
```

This object sgd_clf is a stochastic gradient descent classifier **which was previously fitted with the train data in the previous section**. My question is: why, if already fitted, it is better to split the train set in three parts and retrain (?) the sgd_clf in two of them, then make a prediction and so on, if sgd_clf is already trained? Why not just let it predict on full X_train? Or just take a new not-fitted classifier as imput? Why put sgd_clf already trained as imput to retrain? I am a bit confused.

Answer (score 0):

I see your confusion and I think Geron doesn't mean you should use the fitted model for cross-validation. He just wants to compare the naive fitting method with cross-validation.

The complete code should be as follows:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier

# No cross-validation
sgd_clf1 = SGDClassifier(random_state=42)
sgd_clf1.fit(X_train, y_train)

# With cross-validation
sgd_clf2 = SGDClassifier(random_state=42)
cross_val_score(sgd_clf2, X_train, y_train, cv=3, scoring='accuracy')
```